# Project Hail Mary - differences in audiobook

Tags: andy-weir, project-hail-mary

The [Audible listing for 'Project Hail Mary'](https://www.audible.co.uk/pd/Project-Hail-Mary-Audiobook/B08GB2RLKM?qid=1642073817&sr=1-1&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_1&pf_rd_p=c6e316b8-14da-418d-8f91-b3cad83c5183&pf_rd_r=MZ8ER6DK689N1B02PQ00) By Andy Weir states:

> PLEASE NOTE: To accommodate this audio edition, some changes to the original text have been made with the approval of author Andy Weir.

After reading the book I can't see any thing that would need to be changed for the audiobook version ?

After a discussion with a friend we determined that 'Rocky's' voice is represented as musical notes in the audiobook but we couldn't work out any other differences.

So, what changes have been made to the original text for the audiobook version ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got the 'official' answer from Andy Weir:

> Yeah it's just the change of musical notes to actual music. And the occasional correction of grammar that had slipped through the copyeditors of the print edition.
> -ATW